# LINQ to Entities Update Record

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am new to using LINQ with Entities i have the following which i am trying to run a update on.

```
 OEEPumaDBEntities PumaOEEModel = new OEEPumaDBEntities();
 Parameter1 parameter = new Parameter1();
 parameter.ProductionWarning = int.Parse(txtProductionWarning.Text);
 parameter.ProductionDistress = int.Parse(txtProductionDistress.Text);
 parameter.ShiftStart = cmbShiftStart.Text;

 try
 {
     PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();

 }
 catch
 {
     throw new Exception("Could not save changes.");  
 }
```

When i run the code it debugs fine and does not catch any errors. But when i check the SQL db it has not updated the record with the new data. I have changed the code and can add new row but for some reason i cant update the record. Can anyone see any issues with the above code and advice on how i could change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to insert a new entity, need to first attach it to the database context:

```
PumaOEEModel.Parameters.Add(parameter);
```

If you're updating an object, you need to first find it.
So instead of `parameter = new Parameter()` you'd load it:

```
var parameter = PumaOEEModel.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ParameterId == 1);
```

(Assuming your `PumaOEEModel` is a data context.)

Comment: There is also nice method `Find()` which will save you database query if entity already exist in context

Answer (score 1):

You need to retrieve an entity from your `PumaOEEModel` and then update the properties on it before calling `PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges()`.  Something like the following.  BTW, you need to properly dispose of OEEPumaDBEntities with a using block.

```
using (var PumaOEEModel = new OEEPumaDBEntities())
{
    Parameter1 parameter = PumaOEEModel.Parameters.Single(p => p.Id == 1);

    parameter.ProductionWarning = int.Parse(txtProductionWarning.Text);
    parameter.ProductionDistress = int.Parse(txtProductionDistress.Text);
    parameter.ShiftStart = cmbShiftStart.Text;

    try
    {
        PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not save changes.");  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to update the Parameter1 object parameter.
In your code however, you're initializing a new Parameter1 object instead of getting the object you want to update from the SQL db.

Comment: This should probably be a comment

Comment: @christiandev can't "comment" yet, not enough rep ;)

Comment: Really? :) OK, my bad in that case... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
OEEPumaDBEntities PumaOEEModel = new OEEPumaDBEntities();
var parameter = PumaOEEModel.Parameters.Single(x => x.ID == myParameterId);
parameter.ProductionWarning = int.Parse(txtProductionWarning.Text);
parameter.ProductionDistress = int.Parse(txtProductionDistress.Text);
parameter.ShiftStart = cmbShiftStart.Text;
PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
    OEEPumaDBEntities PumaOEEModel = new OEEPumaDBEntities();

    // id here is the id of the record you want to update
    Parameter1 parameter = PumaOEEModel.Parameter1.Singl(p=>p.ID == id);

    parameter.ProductionWarning = int.Parse(txtProductionWarning.Text);
    parameter.ProductionDistress = int.Parse(txtProductionDistress.Text);
    parameter.ShiftStart = cmbShiftStart.Text;

    try
    {
        PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();

    }
    catch
    {
        throw new Exception("Could not save changes.");  
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `AddObject` if it's a **new object**, for example...

```
PumaOEEModel.AddObject(parameter);
PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();
```

or `Attach` if it's an **update**

```
var parameter = context.PumaOEEModel.Find(PrimaryKey); 
//update parameter properties
PumaOEEModel.Attach(parameter);
PumaOEEModel.SaveChanges();
```